# Disable Add/edit categories in WYSIWYG editor - MediaWiki

Tags: ckeditor, mediawiki, wysiwyg, mediawiki-extensions

I want to disable /hide the Add/edit categories button in WYSIWYG editor based on the user group.

That is, that category creation option should be visible only for bureaucrat and sysop ( admin ). For other user groups/ other registered users, this option should be either disabled or hidden.

I have added the below code in localsettings.php.

```
 require_once( "$IP/extensions/WYSIWYG/WYSIWYG/WYSIWYG.php" );
 $wgGroupPermissions['*']['wysiwyg'] = true;
```

The above code allows all users to use the WYSIWYG editor. But i want to restrict category creation only to bureaucrat & sysop.[image: Editor toolbar]

You can see a "C" icon in the toolbar which is to add/edit categories . I want to restrict the display of the C icon to bureaucrats only. Other user groups shouldnot be able to add categories using that C icon from toolbar. So i want to hide or disable that icon based on the logged in user group.

How to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediaWiki - Restrict category creation to particular user group / bureaucrat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177453/mediawiki-restrict-category-creation-to-particular-user-group-bureaucrat)

Comment: @leo I would deduplicate the other way around - the question is much more clearly stated here.

Comment: You can see what groups the current user is in with `mw.config.get('wgUserGroups')`. The rest is more of a CKEditor question than a MediaWiki question.

Comment: @Tgr Good point. Done.